# Simple page at admin panel - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to create a simple page and display it at admin panel. My page is very simple. I just want write list of elements from database.

I know how get data from database and create page using templates. But I don' t know how to create page that will be at admin panel and will need admin authentication.

It is possible to do it without creating plugin? How I can do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a plugin as it is not hard to pull your code in. I am onmy mobile I apologies for not being thorough. Although integrating it into the theme isn't bad either.

Here is a link to the example/docs on how to add an admin page into dashboard. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus

Comment: You are right. Creating plugin is very easy. I decided to create plugin using this tutorial: http://ditio.net/2007/08/09/how-to-create-wordpress-plugin-from-a-scratch/ I never think creating plugin is so easy. I thought it is very hard. Thanks for Your post.

Comment: The one part I get hung up on is learning the add_action and add_filter hooks. Ones you learn these, theme and plugin development is powerful!